# tf__vae_loss() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'z_log_var' and 'z_mean'

Tags: python, autoencoder

I am writing Python with Jupyter notebook and I am encountering the following error:

```
TypeError: outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__vae_loss() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'z_log_var' and 'z_mean'
```

This error occurs when I attempt to run the following code:

```
vae.fit(x_train, x_train,
        shuffle=True,
        epochs=nb_epoch,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
        verbose=1)
```

The `vae_loss` code is as follows:

```py
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean, z_log_var, z_mean):
    reconstruction_loss = losses.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean) * original_dim
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    return K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
```

here's the full code :-

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K
from keras import losses
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

batch_size = 100
original_dim = 28*28 
latent_dim = 2
intermediate_dim = 256
nb_epoch = 5 
epsilon_std = 1.0

x = Input(shape=(original_dim,), name="input") 
h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu', name="encoding")(x) 
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name="mean")(h) 
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name="log-variance")(h) 

def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0.)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon

z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var]) 
encoder = Model(x, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder") 

input_decoder = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name="decoder_input") 
decoder_h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu', name="decoder_h")(input_decoder)
x_decoded = Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid', name="flat_decoded")(decoder_h) 
decoder = Model(input_decoder, x_decoded, name="decoder")

output_combined = decoder(encoder(x)[2]) 
vae = Model(x, output_combined) 
vae.summary() 

def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean, z_log_var, z_mean):
    reconstruction_loss = losses.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    return K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)



vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=vae_loss)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))



vae.fit(x_train, x_train,
        shuffle=True,
        epochs=nb_epoch,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
        verbose=1)
```

Can anyone help me solve this error? Thanks in advance.